# Creating a site from scratch, first thing to code, Master Page, header, menu or what?

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, master-pages

I am to create a website with ASP.net, I have the design with myself. It is a normal website
It is my first time and I do not know to start from where.
I mean what are the steps, like first menu then master page or header, footer.....
Appreciate in order way answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter: you should first and foremost analyze the site's intended functionality, and start building that; the design should follow this (build the main part first, the other stuff only when you need it), not the other way around. Bad car analogy: first of all, figure out whether you're building a light, solar-powered racing car, or a SUV, or a 18-wheel truck; choosing the paint color is the *last* step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a prototype in HTML. No master pages, no routing, no views, controllers, inheritance. None of that.

Make a prototype of the most complex page and of the simplest page. You'll then see how to organise your layout. I'm not going to speak about architecture of the application as the topic is too broad. I assume that all this is already in place and you are asking how to build your presentation layer.

Create a basic master page that would just have a wrapper. Inherit from that master page so that you have header, main content and footer. Then adapt this to your need by introducing further inheritance if needed.

In regards to views and controllers and stuff.

I'd create those in the following way:

1. View model
2. View
3. Controller
4. Routing

This is very basic and by no means a template that will always work, but hopefully it'll give you something to think about.